# Cors Issue In Ionic View

Tags: ionic2

Hello i have deployed my project in ionic view where i need to make a http call to remote server.I have implemented proxies like this

```
{
 "name": "MobileUI",
 "app_id": "608c237d",
 "type": "ionic-angular",
 "proxies": [
   {
    "path": "/Auth",
    "proxyUrl": "https://example.com/Auth/Authenticate",
     "rejectUnauthorized": false
    }
  ]
}
```

And I make a login call to the from the provider like this

```
  AuthenticateUser(username: string, password: string) {
var userNamePwd: any = {};
userNamePwd.username = username;
userNamePwd.password = password;
let body = JSON.stringify(userNamePwd);
let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
return this.http.post('/Auth', body, options)
  .map((res) => {
    let data = this.extractData(res);
    this.storage.set('id_token', data[0].Token);
    this.sharedAuth.SetEntityData(data);
    return data;
  })
  .catch(this.handleError);
 }
```

The Login works perfectly when testing in web browser but when i upload the app in my ionic view i am getting this error `response with status 0 for url null`
I implemented the proxies in the way mentioned in http://blog.ionic.io/handling-cors-issues-in-ionic/ .
Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 0):

the issue is that when you run the app in ionic view app, there is no local proxy to forward requests to your backend. So you get into cors issues because the local webview enforce strict cors in the ionic view app.

I hope the ionic team comes up with a fix. As for now, to my best knowledge, you should modify your backend to allow all origins, or use a web server as a proxy to forward your request to your api servers.